# Documenting functions contained in Objects with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I’m looking for a way to document functions contained in a Dictionary in Javascript with JSDoc 3.

Even though I tell JSDoc there is a function with `@function`, it is not included in the generated documentation.

Is there a JSDoc tag that could help? Or is there a more convenient approach than mine?

Thanks

```
/**
 * @namespace Minitel
 */ 
var Minitel = Minitel || {}

/**
 * @callback actionCallback 
 * @param {Stream} stream The Minitel Stream to which add the Videotex codes
 * @param {Object} data Data object
 * @param {?number} offsetX X offset
 * @param {?number} offsetY Y offset
 */

/**
 * Action callbacks
 * @member {Object.<string, actionCallback>}
 */
Minitel.actions = {}

/**
 * Handles "content-string" actions. The value should already be ready to be
 * sent in the stream.
 * @function
 */
Minitel.actions["content-string"] = function(stream, data) {
    /* ... */
}

/**
 * Handles "content-block" actions. It only supports left, center and right
 * alignment.
 * @function
 */
Minitel.actions["content-block"] = function(stream, data, offsetX, offsetY) {
    /* ... */
}
```

I’m using `jsdoc -p -c jsdoc.json app/*.js library/minitel/*.js` to generate the documentation

Here is `jsdoc.json`:

```
{
    "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
    "opts": {
        "template": "../docdash"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure (as jsdoc is not verbose sometimes) but it looks like `@member` can not have children. A solution can be to use `@namespace`.

So your `actions` will be documented as follows:

```
/**
 * Action callbacks
 * @namespace
 */
```

One issue with `@namespace` is that you cannot define a type for it. But in this case all methods are documented even without `@function` as static ones.